# nagios -- disable notifications for this service on all hosts?

Tags: nagios

I know it's easy to pick a host and "Disable notifications for all services on this host".  But I have an issue where (for example) I know that my NTP server is going to be down for two weeks.  I would like to "Disable notifications for this service on all hosts" ... and, once it's fixed, "Enable notifications for this service on all hosts".  Is there an easy one-click solution?

Answer (score 2):

Nagios [service groups](https://assets.nagios.com/downloads/nagioscore/docs/nagioscore/4/en/objectdefinitions.html#servicegroup) can be used to accomplish this.  Beside letting you easily see the status of related services, you can also bring up a menu which allows you to disable notifications for all services in that group, among other things.

On the Service Groups page in the Nagios web interface, the long description of a group (`alias`) links to a status page, while the short name (`servicegroup_name`, displayed in parentheses) links to the actions menu.

The documentation for the [check_openmanage plugin](http://folk.uio.no/trondham/software/check_openmanage.html#getting-started) is a good example for this, as it uses both host groups and service groups.  The service definition assigns the "Dell OMSA" service to all hosts in the "dell-servers" hostgroup, and also places it in a "dell-openmanage" service group.  The only per-host configuration required is adding "dell-servers" to its `hostgroups` setting.

Thanks to that service group, you could easily enable or disable notifications, schedule downtime, etc. for the "Dell OMSA" service on all hosts.  Hopefully it makes sense how you might adapt this for your NTP clients.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably use Scheduled Downtime when you know the start and end times; use Enable/Disable Notifications only when you don't know the start/end times.

Documentation on Configuring Downtime in Nagios XI:
https://support.nagios.com/kb/article.php?id=544

Comment: I appreciate the input, but it doesn't answer my question about "this service on all hosts"